# JExcel : Saving a workbook without closing it

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I am running long computations (run time measured in days) and I am saving the results to an Excel worksheet using the JExcel API. I would like to save the results to disk at regular intervals to prevent any loss of data due to, say, power outages or unforeseen computer crashes.

My question is : how do I go about doing this in a reasonable way? Only calling write() in WritableWorkbook does not work, and closing the work book using close() would require reopening the work book afterwards which is pretty cumbersome. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use the [`JExcel API`](http://www.teamdev.com/jexcel) (i.e. the API of `JExcel`) or the [`JExcelApi`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I assume you use JExcelApi. What did you tried? Did you wrote some code?